# Clojure: Attaching annotations to AOT-compiled methods

Tags: clojure

I have a module for the [BaseX](http://basex.org/) [Java interface](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Java_Bindings) which I'm writing in Clojure. The interface provides a number of annotations which can be used to determine how methods are called and optimized; however, I'm having trouble getting these to actually attach to the generated class:

```
(ns net.dyfis.svnkit_wrapper.SvnWrapper
  (:import (org.basex.query QueryModule
                            QueryModule$Requires
                            QueryModule$Permission
                            QueryModule$Deterministic))
  (:gen-class
    :main false
    :extends org.basex.query.QueryModule
    :methods [
      ^{:static true}
      [^{QueryModule$Requires QueryModule$Permission/NONE,
         Deprecated {}}
       cat [java.lang.String] java.lang.String]

      ^{:static true}
      [^{QueryModule$Deterministic {},
         QueryModule$Requires QueryModule$Permission/NONE}
       catRev [java.lang.String int] java.lang.String]]))
```

However, only the Deprecated annotation gets attached -- the `QueryModule$Requires` and  `QueryModule$Deterministic` annotations are silently discarded:

```
>>> cat
public static java.lang.String net.dyfis.svnkit_wrapper.SvnWrapper.cat(java.lang.String)
>>> cat.getAnnotations()
array(java.lang.annotation.Annotation,[@java.lang.Deprecated()])
```

This is happening with Clojure 1.4.0-beta6, whereas support for annotations in AOT-compiled methods is supposed to be present from Clojure 1.2. As such, this is presumably a usage error -- but what should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 2):

Except for classes in `java.lang` (like `Deprecated`), all classnames must be fully qualified in `gen-class` declarations.  So, your code should be:

```
^{org.basex.query.QueryModule$Deterministic {},
  org.basex.query.QueryModule$Requires org.basex.query.QueryModule$Permission/NONE}
```

Note that the same restriction does not apply to annotation metadata on/in `deftype`, `defprotocol`, or `defrecord` forms.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the `gen-class` definition out of the `ns` declaration allowed the `import`s to apply:

```
(ns net.dyfis.svnkit_wrapper.SvnWrapper
  (:import (org.basex.query QueryModule
                            QueryModule$Requires
                            QueryModule$Permission
                            QueryModule$Deterministic)))

(gen-class
  :name com.indeed.svnkit_wrapper.SvnWrapper
  :main false
  :extends org.basex.query.QueryModule
  :methods [
    ^{:static true}
    [^{QueryModule$Requires QueryModule$Permission/NONE,
       Deprecated {}}
     cat [java.lang.String] java.lang.String]

    ^{:static true}
    [^{QueryModule$Deterministic {},
       QueryModule$Requires QueryModule$Permission/NONE}
     catRev [java.lang.String long] java.lang.String]
  ])
```